# Making sense of the decomposition plot in R

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition

I'm trying to understand what does the decomposition function and plot actually indicate. I'm using the following as an example:

```
library(TTR)
t <- ts(co2, frequency=12, start=1, deltat=1/12)
td <- decompose(t)
plot(td)
```

I'm not quite sure what the seasonal component and random component actually tells us.

Specifically, why does the seasonal graph fluctuates between -3 and + 2, for all time. Shouldn't it have similar fluctuations as the observed series? And what does actually the range between -3 and +2 mean?

Furthermore, what does the random component actually say? Are those the residual errors, and seasonal + random = observed???

Any help will be greatly appreciated since i am quite confused at this point. Decomposed graph looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can answer this yourself really, by accessing the components using `$`

```r
library(TTR)
t <- ts(co2, frequency=12, start=1, deltat=1/12)
td <- decompose(t)
```

Here's the seasonal component on its own:

```
plot(td$seasonal)
```

[image]

Now add the trend:

```r
plot(td$seasonal + td$trend)
```

[image]

and finally the random component:

```r
plot(td$seasonal + td$trend + td$random)
```

[image]

and compare this to the original data:

```r
plot(td$x)
```

[image]

So the time series is decomposed into a seasonal component, which by definition repeats without variation, a trend line around which the seasonal component varies, and a "random" component which is akin to residuals.

<sup>Created on 2020-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Allan. Would you say that the random component offers any information about users' behavior? For example could you attribute any large spikes to particular events, that might have occurred? This is a general question and not specific to this dataset. Thanks

Comment: @XristosSolwmou it depends on the nature of the deviation. Some types of deviation might be picked up by the trend component, though transient spikes wouldn’t be, and could be due to other explanatory factors.

Comment: Thanks @Allan. Would you say that large spikes (large deviation) worth looking into? So if there are certain events that occurred in the same date as the large spikes, could we conclude that were a result of those events? Again, i'm referring to up-normal spikes with large deviation

Comment: @XristodSolwmou it’s worth exploring, but it’s not possible to say with the information given. You could present the data over at the stats stack exchange site where you are likely to get a better answer.